# Build 64bit GNU GMP for GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, codeblocks, gmp

Many of links I have tried have said to follow the same steps,

```
install MSYS2
install GCC
run ./configure
run make
run make install
run make check
```

in the directory of the GMP files. I have tried this and it has never worked.
The only thing that has worked for me was installing MSYS (not MSYS2) and selecting a MinGW compiler from CodeBlocks to then run the above instructions. It has worked then for 32bit programs, however I don't know how to get it working for 64bit programs.

On my latest attempt, I tried running `./configure "CFLAGS=-m64" "CXXFLAGS=-m64" "LDFLAGS=-m64" && make` and then the remaining steps. This still ended me up in the same place as running just `./configure`.

I thought if the above didn't work for 64bit, then surely it would work for 64bit (the `./configure` solution), however it doesn't.

On 32bit, I get these errors:

```
undefined reference to __gmpz_init
... more of the above but for different gmp functions
```

and on 64bit I get these errors (this is what I am trying to compile for):

```
undefined reference to `__getreent`
and this ^ repeats a lot of times.
```

I can't find any guides online about installing GMP-64bit, rather 32bit and that uses MSYS, which is what I had working initially, however that is only for 32bit and an outdated compiler.

How can I install 64bit GMP to use in a CodeBlocks Project using a MinGW 64bit compiler?

Comment: Doesn't msys2 have a GMP package, so you could install GMP the same way you installed GCC? https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-gmp seems to indicate that they do.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yep, that did work. Thanks! Just as a note, though, it seems to crash after requesting `(size=4294959136)` bytes, which is 2^32. This seems odd, since the program is running as 64bit. Any ideas?

Comment: That could be another question, where you would post the testcase so people can reproduce, details about how you compiled, etc.